# Why service should not start activity?

Tags: android, service

In the status notification doc [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) i read :

> A background service **should never launch** an activity on its own
>   in order to receive user interaction. The service should instead
>   create a status notification that will launch the activity when
>   selected by the user.

Why this "should not" ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: beacause It would be effing annoying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely from a user-experience perspective. If you start an Activity from a background process it looks and feels odd to the user. It is quite obtrusive to just stop the user in the middle of whatever they are doing so that your app can take priority. A status bar notification gives them the option to respond as necessary, or ignore the action for as long as they see fit.

Answer (score 6):

Because services happen in the background, so the user is very likely doing something else while your service is running. If you interrupt whatever they were doing by just dropping your activity on top of it they will be at best confused, and at worst annoyed.

They suggest to use a notification because then the user is alerted that you'd like to start an activity but they can choose to start it "on their own time" whenever they are ready to by tapping it in the notification bar.

Comment: Was just typing basically this. :) Have a +1

Answer (score 1):

Your service doesn't know what the user is doing at the moment it wants to get user interaction. If user is in another application, creating a new activity would kill (or at least put to sleep) the other application, potentially disturbing the user (if he is gaming you could kill the game, if he is doing something more serious it could be even more damaging).