# Dismiss android activity displayed as Popup

Tags: android, popup, android-listview, android-activity

So i have a service, that starts an activity displayed as a Popup thank's to "android:style/Theme.Dialog"

This Activity shows a Listview, with a list of application.
On each element of the listview, there is a short description of the application, and two buttons.
1 for launching the application
2 for displaying a toast with more informations.

Here is the code in my service : it starts the activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PopUpActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

this activity uses a custom layout, with a listview, adapted with a custom ArrayAdapter

In this adaptater, i've put an action on the start button in order to start the current application

```
Button lanceur = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Buttonlancer);
            lanceur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    p.start(mcontext);
                }
            });
```

with p.start, i start the application.

But now, if i press "back" from the application, i go back to the popup... and i can start another application. I don't want it to be possible.

That's why i wish i could dismiss/destroy/finish my PopupActivity, but i can't manage to do it with the code i have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `startActivityForResult()` and  `onActivityResult()`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, PopUpActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 getApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(intent,1); 

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     Log.d("CheckStartActivity","onActivityResult and resultCode = "+resultCode);
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     this.finish();
 }
```

and add in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<activity android:name=".PopUpActivity" android:noHistory="true" />`

Comment: Thank's
I wish i could use startActivityForResult, but my activity is not started from another activity, so i cant use it. I've read i can start a "fake" activity, witch starts my activity with "startActivityForResult".
Is that a good idea ?

Comment: @Sit : a your code posted in question you are starting your PopUpActivity using Intent means from Another Activity or from any other component.so if you are starting your popup Activity from any other Component then you are right start an "FAKE" Activity.

Comment: Alright thank you, i'm done with this, thank's to the FakeActivity with onActivityResult method;)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` inside your `Activity` that is displayed as pop-up, after calling `start` for your next `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you, but the activity doesnt start the popup herself, it's done with the button, and its code is implemented in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

change your luanch code like this:

```
Button lanceur = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Buttonlancer);
lanceur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        p.start(mcontext);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Also you probably shouldn't need to be calling getApplicationContext() in your Service can you paste some more code? You should be able to use `NameOfYourService.this.startActivity();` or perhaps even just `startActivity();` depending on how you have it structured.

Also note as per the [Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) it is a ***very bad idea*** for you to start an Activity directly from a service. see this question for reasons why: [Why service should not start activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263772/why-service-should-not-start-activity/11263843#11263843)

Comment: thank's for our answer.
I'm aware a service should not start a popup nor an activity, but i'm doing an app' with a behaviour close to "sms popup".
The goal there is to display a popup when receiving calls, or calling.

I can not add "finish" in the code as you suggested me, because the button's code is in the Adaptater class, who does not extend any sort of activity :/